# MonoDroid/MonoDevelop: Interactive debugger isn't working

Tags: android, android-emulator, monodevelop, xamarin.android

The interactive debugger works fine on one computer. But on another, which I configured the same way, I am having these problems...

When I try to run my android application from MonoDevelop the "Select Device" window is empty. There are three emulators listed in the AVD manager. (On my other computer I see all three emulators in the Select Device window.)

If I manually start an emulator it does appear. The Ok button never lights up, but if I double-click on it my application will deploy. However the debugger isn't working. Breakpoints are not honored and any exception will simply crash the application. I can see Debug.WriteLine info.

- I tried restarting the adb server using the Refresh button.
- I tried restarting the adb server from the command line.
- I tried restarting my computer.
- I tried uninstalling and reinstalling Mono for Android and its dependencies

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you are using MonoDevelop on Windows, this is a recent bug that should be fixed in the next release:

http://bugzilla.xamarin.com/show_bug.cgi?id=2196